# Like button does not show faces

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a like button set with a certain url. The problem is that it doesn't show the faces. This is the code:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=225460250806615";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.nu.nl/binnenland/2936758/verfbommen-huis-minister-leers.html" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no one in your friend list did like the url (data-href) before, you can't see any face.